# Can I add my repo before the "Requires" in .spec file of rpm package?

Tags: centos7, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Here is a problem:

- I need to install package in CentOS 7 (let's call it "testpack") from my own rpm-package. Thanks to guys from Stackoverflow, I know that I need to install this testpack from "Requires" section of .spec file, but the testpack need to be installed from non-default repository.

Here is a question:

- How can I add non-default repository within .spec file which has a string "Requires: testpack"? Adding new repository and installing testpack need to do from the same package. Is it possible?

Here is my strange pre-solutions:

- try to add string like that `curl http://domain.com/testpack_repo.sh | bash /dev/stdin arg1` in `%pre` and `%prep` section of .spec file, but that section is launch only while rpm is making with `rpmbuild --bb test.spec`. If I try to install this package in other system with `yum install test.rpm` this section is ignored;
- try to add `curl http://domain.com/testpack_repo.sh | bash /dev/stdin arg1` in `%post` section without hope. This section is ignored during `yum install test.rpm` because of testpack installing from "Requires" were failed;
- try to use bash script with curl instead naked curl - got the same result;
- try to use `echo repo_info > repo_file` in different section of .spec file - failed again.

Here is my .spec file:

```
Name: test_script_name
Summary: It's just a test_script_summary
Version: 0.1 
Release: 1
Group: Applications/Internet
License: GPL 
Requires: testpack
BuildArch: noarch
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-root

%description
A test_script_description.

%pre
curl http://domain.com/test.sh | bash /dev/stdin arg1

%prep 
%build
%install
%clean
%post
#bash test.sh
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)

%changelog
* Tue Dec 08 2015 test test <test@test.com>
- test_script_changelog!
```

I hope for help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

You can make a single RPM that the user downloads that then drops your GPG key and repo location files in the appropriate locations.

Take a look at something like https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm to see how they do it for EPEL.